# IE 11 window.open file:// results in JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, window.open

We have an intranet site, and our users use IE 11.
On IE 11, on the URL I can type in 
file:///C:/myLocalMachineFolder/myFile.pdf
or
file:///myServer/myFolder/myFile.pdf

On myServer, I created a Virtual directory myFolder that points to a folder on myServer.

But, if I do this in from the code (from a View)

```
return window.open("file:///C:/myLocalMachineFolder/myFile.pdf");
```

or

```
return window.open("file:///myServer/myFolder/myFile.pdf");
```

I get the error: 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied

What can I do to fix it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Probably nothing. Opening a local file from JavaScript is not possible.

Comment: Publish your pdf documents to a folder on the intranet web site then use //sitename/folder/myfile.pdf or a relative path.

Comment: Did you mean to use http://sitename/folder/myfile.pdf instead of file:///myServer/myFolder/myFile.pdf ? Unfortunately, if I use http://sitename/folder/myfile.pdf, I am unable to drag and drop the PDF file as an attachment to Outlook email. 
If I use file:///myServer/myFolder/myFile.pdf, I will be able to.